# How to configure the multiplexer select of the ADC ad7266 in the device tree?

Tags: linux, arm, device-tree, adc

I am using a Freescale i.mx28 board. There is a ad7266 that communicate with the cpu over SPI. The ad7266 has a multiplexer that works with three GPIOs. (A0, A1, A2). In the past I configure this GPIOs directly in the driver. Now I want to use a second ad7266 over another SPI-Bus. Now, of course cannot config the multiplexer directly in the driver. So my question is, how can I config this Pins in the device tree? Is that possible? Here the code snippet:

```
        ssp2: ssp@80014000 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            compatible = "fsl,imx28-spi";
            pinctrl-names = "default";  
            pinctrl-0 = <&spi2_pins_pwr003>;
            status = "okay";                    

            flash: m25p80@0 {
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <1>;
                compatible = "sst,sst25vf016b";
                spi-max-frequency = <40000000>;
                reg = <0>;
            };          

            AD7266_PWR003: AD7266@0 {
                compatible = "adi,ad7266";
                spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
                spi-cpol;
                vref-supply = <&reg_vref_2p5v>;
                reg = <1>;
            };


        };
```

Thanks

Comment: As I found out the driver don't does not have devicetree support.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out the driver don't does not have devicetree support. – eddi